# Yahoo Finance Dividend History Table Missing

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I've been using the Yahoo Dividend History table for a stock app I've created for many years. Today it was missing, screwing up the whole app.

Check for yourself here:

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+Symbol%2C+Dividends%2C+Date+from+yahoo.finance.dividendhistory+where+startDate+%3D+%22%22+and+endDate+%3D+%22%22+and+symbol+in+(%22GRX%22)

And here is a picture proving it.
[image]

I asked this question a while back and then it turned out that it either showed up again or I had made a mistake. I'm not certain which. This time I know for sure it's missing.

So two questions: 1) Why would it go missing and can anyone fix it? Who can? 2) Is there an alternative source I can use instead. Maybe a Div History api for Yahoo or from somewhere else?

Comment: I tried adding ''public' to the query that is being generated below and I came up with: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20Symbol%2C%20Dividends%2C%20Date%20from%20yahoo.finance.dividendhistory%20where%20startDate%20%3D%20%22%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%22%22%20and%20symbol%20in%20(%22grx%22)&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys - but it still won't work. Maybe the table is not public anymore?

Comment: It may have been removed. Some YQL is created by users, not Yahoo. This could be one of them? It's frustrating not knowing how to fix it.